# Where can I find data on the number of single propeller aircraft currently in operation in the EU and US?

Tags: usa, datasets, single-engine, eu

Are there publicly available data for aircraft registered in operation?

Specifically I am looking for number of single propeller aircraft in US/EU, ideally with aircraft types as well. However, any useful data of this sort would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the help center and [the tour page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour). Resource location (e.g., where to find x) is typically [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead, you can, if possible, ask a question that relates to the underlying problem that requires said resource/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the entire [FAA aircraft registration database](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/releasable_aircraft_download/) and analyze it however you want.

I have no idea about EASA, but because aircraft registration is delegated to member states you'll probably have to look at each one individually (e.g. [the UK](https://www.caa.co.uk/Aircraft-register/G-INFO/Guidance-on-using-the-G-INFO-Database/)). I don't know if all EASA countries consider aircraft registration information to be public or not.

You could also look for a commercial data provider that sells the data you need, of course.